# angular router changes url but does not load the components / pages

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

i have this nav component

```
<div class="mx">
  <ul class="xv">
    <li
      *ngFor="let item of items"
      class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--{{ item.theme }}"
    >
      <a
        routerLink="{{ item.category == 'home' ? '' : item.endpoint }}"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
        >{{ item.title }} </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

in the app-routing

```
  {
    path: ":section/:layout/:layout_2/:site/:section",
    component: HomePageComponent,
  },

  {
    path: ":site/:section/:year/:month/:day/:title",
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: ArticlePageComponent

  },
 {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    component: HomePageComponent
  },
...
```

so I'm loading the same component but with different data e.g `HomePageComponent`

so the router only move to a section page from the root/home page
but if in section page already it won't switch to another section page only go back to home page

Comment: urls are veery strange in your app, but I assume you can easy fix your app by adding pathMatch: 'full' to the upper route, or put ArticlePageComponent route before the upper path

Comment: @Andrei, still the same changed the order and added  pathMatch: "full"

Comment: post your item object, what is in item.endpoint?

Comment: @SnehaPawar, item.endpoint is url sting  e.g `/section/layout/layout_2/site/sports` which will be added to the basepath so the full URL wil be `www.www.com/section/layout/layout_2/site/sports`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your whole paths are "variable", because they only consists out of parameters.
The URL itself contains then only the value of the params, but not the param-names.
Therefor the router could not distinguish the routes (only perhaps if the amount of variables is different).

Change your url for example to

```
path: "section/:section/layout/:layout/layout_2/:layout_2/site/:site/section/:section"
```

then the router has a chance to distinguish the routes based on the "static" parts.

Comment: thanks for this point, if I change the list of paths to static it works, so it is a matte of variables